# How to get ping time in nanoseconds?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ping, utility, traceroute

when i ping to 192.168.11.101 it is giving in ping time in ms like

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.11.101:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms
```

i need this time in nano seconds (ns) .

Comment: Measuring fibre optic networks be like <1ms .. Tell me precisely how much!! ;] Great question man. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find utilities that work at nanosecond resolution since operating systems aren't that precise. But on windows you can get microsecond resolution using [hrPing](http://www.cfos.de/en/ping/ping.htm).

[image]

Comment: Awesome software man! I attached an image to show the difference for Fibre optic Cable and Cat5E LAN. Pretty awesome tool

Comment: They are that precise. Here is for Linux https://github.com/ymirsky/burstPing and here is needed documentation for Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps